# Can't access object properties in angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

I'm trying to set an object that is called channelid with the property channel. However when I try to access it I return Object {    }

Service

```
function Service($http){
  var service = this;
  var channelid = {};

  // Set channel ID
  service.SetChannelID = function(id){
    channelid.channel = id;
  };

  // Get Channel Id
  service.GetChannelID = function(){
    return channelid;
  };
```

Controller

```
// Set channel id
Service.SetChannelID(channel.id);

// Retrieve channel id
var channelID = Service.GetChannelID();
```

When I try to access it.

```
console.log(channelID.channel);
```

It prints undefined

if I print

```
console.log(channelID);
```

It prints object {}

```
>Object
  channel:"C3NBGTQJD"
  __proto__: Object
```

not object{channel:"C3NBGTQJD"}

Comment: because `channelid` is private variable of `Service` function.. You can not access via `Service` function instance...You could get that value only via `getter` & `setter` that you already had

Comment: `Service.SetChannelID` doesn't seem defined. `SetChannelID` is only defined on the instances of `Service`, not on the constructor function itself.

Comment: Service is a class / constructor function. Did you create a instance of it? var service = new Service(); And then call the methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference you can follow this fiddle

```
"http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/9158/"
```

Service

```
  myApp.service('myService', function(){
  var channelObj={};
  var service = this;

  service.setChannelId = function(id) {
    channelObj.channel = id;
  };

  service.getChannel = function() {
    return channelObj;
  }

});
```

Controller

```
$scope.setChannelId = function (id) {
        myService.setChannelId(id);
}

$scope.getChannelId = function() {
        var channelObj = myService.getChannel()
        alert(channelObj.channel);
}
```

template

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <button ng-click="setChannelId(5)">
    Set Channel
  </button>
  <button ng-click="getChannelId()">
    Get Channel
  </button>

</div>
```

Comment: What i'm trying to achieve is this:
     var channelObj = myService.getChannel();


     function GetChannelDataById(channelObj.channel);


     function GetChannelDataById(id){
      // do something
     }